# How to create a soft link without path of the parent directories in linux?

Tags: linux, symlink

We are creating a soft link using below command.

`ln -sf /home/root/Test "/home/root/TestSoftLink"`

So our TestSoftLink will be pointing to /home/root/Test

`TestSoftLink -> /home/root/Test`

Our requirement : When we do `ll` under `/home/root/` TestSoftLink should point to  Test (Without parent directories) like below

**`TestSoftLink -> Test`**

Note : both Test and TestSoftLink should be present under `/home/root/`

Is it possible?

Comment: `cd /root; ln Test TestSoftLink`

Comment: Thanks a ton @cuihtlauac It worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ln -s` command simply takes the string of the first argument, and writes it into the symbolic link. As such, it is perfectly valid to do this:

```
ln -sf Test "/home/root/TestSoftLink"
```

There is no need to do a `cd`.

Answer (score 2):

As @cuihtlauac mentioned , We used below command and it worked !

`cd /home/root; ln -sf Test TestSoftLink`